# How To Retrieve C DATA Value from xml Using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, xpath, cdata

```
<EncounterData Key="3RBD-OS62-SSRN" >
  <RowList /><![CDATA[100]]>
  </EncounterData>
 <EncounterData Key="XI4O-9QM5-DEQ6">
  <RowList /><![CDATA[54]]>
 </EncounterData>
```

In above Xml How to retrieve CDATA Using Key Attribute in PostgreSql Function

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath expression corresponds to the CDATA sections and starts from @Key:

```
@Key/../text()[2]
```

Comment: can you tell me, why it becomes the 2nd element of the array?

Comment: @arthur: The first `text()` child of `EncounterData` is the newline and spaces before `RowList`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the comment. I am asking, since I have an XML document with thousands of entries starting with `@Key` (in my case the key is the same), and every entry has a CDATA tag. Getting [2] there is difficult, as I need to get [2], [5], [8],...,[3n+2],... elements... May I ask what you mean by `RowList`?

Comment: I am really trying to understand, why space and new line are put into separate entries of the text() array..

Comment: There's no text array. There are children of EncounterData: first one is a text() that contains newline and space, the next one is the empty element RowList, the next one is another text() that contains the CDATA, and the last one is text() than contains newline and space.